# how to ssh into nodes of Google container engine cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

how to ssh into nodes of Google container engine cluster? When i try ssh to the node using its ip address it says public key denied.

Can some one help me how to get the key to connect to nodes of google container cluster?

Comment: Can you share some more details? How do you try to connect via ssh (pure `ssh` command, `gcloud ssh` command, via GCP WebUI)? Also, please provide us with the output and errors.

Answer (score 56):

You should use gcloud tool e.g:

```
gcloud compute ssh <NODE_NAME> --zone <ZONE>
```

Comment: thankyou i am able to do it :) it dint strike me the nodes were compute engines too.

Comment: $ gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-b gke-xxx-default-pool-yyy-3q77 -- ps
ssh: connect to host 35.100.100.10 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: @Ark-kun You have to edit the firewall rules of the network that the cluster is on.

Comment: Do note that this adds the key to project metadata (`gcloud compute project-info describe --project PROJECT_ID --format 'yaml(commonInstanceMetadata.items)'`, and a corresponding user is created on every GCE instance of the project. Also you need to add a firewall rule for the ip you're connecting from.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue and after googling few houres founf this workaround.

add firewall rule as below:

Target Tags: tags of GKE nodes

Source IP range : 35.235.240.0/20 (*Cloud IAP's TCP netblock see https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding*)

Port: 22

Then I tired below command

gcloud compute ssh [node name] --zone=[zone]

Comment: This way it works for me when I either use [SSH-in-browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser), or do `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --project PROJECT_ID --zone ZONE --tunnel-through-iap`. If it really worked for you without `--tunnel-through-iap`, then you probably performed some extra steps. To connect without `--tunnel-through-iap` add a firewall rule for your source ip instead. See also [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823760/how-to-ssh-into-nodes-of-google-container-engine-cluster#comment137911219_44828007).

Answer (score -1):

```
kubectl exec -it [POD_NAME] -- /bin/bash
```

You can find the value for the [POD_NAME] by going:

GKE -> Workloads -> click on your workload -> Managed pods -> Name

[[docs 1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/get-shell-running-container/), [docs 2](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/containers/docs/troubleshooting/executing-shell-commands)]

---

*I tried SSH'ing into the container like suggested in other answers, however no matter which zone I chose the response was always "The resource 'projects/...' was not found". Hence I'm leaving this solution as an alternative which allowed me to inspect the files on the deployed container.*

*Update1: Thanks to Glen Yu's comment I managed to get on track for why I couldn't SSH into my node. I've deployed using Autopilot cluster which disallows SSH'ing: "Autopilot blocks SSH access to nodes. GKE handles all operational aspects of the nodes, including node health and all Kubernetes components running on the nodes." [(source)](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-security#:%7E:text=Autopilot%20blocks%20SSH%20access%20to,components%20running%20on%20the%20nodes.). Thanks for pointing it out Glen*

Comment: The question is about NODES not pods